# Event channel is not working as expected between flutter and kotlin

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, flutter-method-channel, event-channel

I did a plugin in native code(Kotlin) and tried to use that in a Flutter application. I used a method channel for Flutter to native code communication and an event channel for native code to Flutter. Method channel communication is working properly, but event channel isn't.

FLUTTER:

```dart
  // will execute this in initState
  EventChannel _eventChannel = EventChannel("STREAM_CHANNEL");
  _eventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream().map((event) => {
         // some actions
      })

  // will execute this by button click (happens after widget got built)
  result =
        await MethodChannel("METHOD_CHANNEL").invokeMethod("functionToInvoke", {
          // payload
        })
```

KOTLIN:

```kotlin
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        startEventChannel(flutterEngine)
        startMethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger)
    }



    fun startMethodChannel(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, 
         "METHOD_CHANNEL").setMethodCallHandler {
             call, result -> when(call.method) {
                 "functionToInvoke" -> {           
                   // some action
                }
            }
        }

    // method not called inspite of calling from configureFlutterEngine
    fun startEventChannel(messenger: BinaryMessenger) {
        eventChannel = EventChannel(messenger, "STREAM_CHANNEL");
        eventChannel.setStreamHandler(
            object : EventChannel.StreamHandler {
                override fun onListen(arguments: Any?, eventSink: EventChannel.EventSink) 
                    {
                        eventSink.success("success")
                    }
            }
        )
    }
```

The `startEventChannel` method is not even called but `startMethodChannel` has been called and methods are registered properly.

There is no issue with the channel names (checked both sides).

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problems:

1. **Stream not listened to:**

   The stream returned by `_eventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream()` is not being listened to. You're only mapping the stream but this callback won't be triggered until you get data in the stream.

   And from your Kotlin `EventChannel` code, data is not added into the stream until you listen to the event channel.
2. **Argument Mismatch:**

   The `startEventChannel` method requires an argument of type `BinaryMessenger` but you're sending it `flutterEngine` which is of type `FlutterEngine`.

### Solution:

1. **Add a listener to the stream:**

   Call `.listen` on the mapped stream from `_eventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream()` like shown below:

   ```dart
    _eventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream().map((event) {}).listen((event) {
       // some actions
    });
   ```
2. **Pass the right argument to `startEventChannel:`**

   Pass the `BinaryMessenger` to the `startEventChannel` instead of the `FlutterEngine`.

   ```kotlin
   startEventChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger)
   ```